# Why is sequential search of ordered list slower than search of unordered one

Tags: data-structures, optimization, program-optimization

I have got assignment to implement set class with linked list, so I first made it with unordered list and time needed to insert million integers is bit less than hour. Then I thought I can get it to work faster by making list ordered (since in average it should take less time to check  is element already in set) but it went running for 1.5h after I stopped it.

In both algorithm there are 2 functions: 1. searches through linked list and returns pointer to predecessor of given element (null if element is not found). In first algorithm before searching for element, element itself is inserted at end of list and after search it is removed (this way there is no need to check if current element is last in search loop). If element is not found second function adds it on beginning of list.

In second algorithm search function does same except it stops after it finds element larger than searched element and returns it address.Then it is inserted in right place.

Integers are randomly generated using built in rand() function.

Update:
I measured average time it takes to find element in both ordered and unordered list and results looks strange to me.

Average times in unordered list
(left is number of elements in list, right is average time spent in search loop in microseconds).

```
10000 :29.4015
20000 :58.7789
30000 :88.0507
40000 :117.39
50000 :146.82
60000 :176.307
70000 :206.139
80000 :236.085
90000 :265.948
100000 :296.426
110000 :326.888
120000 :357.238
```

In ordered list

```
10000 :30.2287
20000 :87.0195
30000 :154.494
40000 :221.932
50000 :292.55
60000 :364.127
70000 :442.623
80000 :527.407
90000 :624.626
100000 :739.803
110000 :869.816
120000 :1008.33
```

Measured pieces of code:

Search in unordered list

```
while(k != current->k){
    old = current;
    current = current->next;
}
```

Search in ordered list

```
while(current->k < k){
    old = current;
    current = current->next;
}
```

In both cases there is guard at and of list, in first case equal to k, and in second larger than k.

Comment: Have you tried estimating the asymptotic running time in both methods?

Comment: From your description it's hard to understand what you did. Can you perhaps clearly explain what you were trying to solve, and which two algorithms you were using?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus In both algorithm there are 2 functions:1. searches through linked list and returns pointer to predecessor of given element(null if element is not found).In first algorithm before searching for element element itself inserted to end of list and after search it is removed(this way there is no need to check if current element is last in search loop).If element is not found second function adds it on beginning of list.In second algorithm search function does same except it stops after it finds element larger than searched element and returns it address.Then it is added in right place

Comment: Please add this information to your post.

Comment: Sorry but fixing your code is off-topic here and, in any case, it's impossible to know what you've done because you don't say with any precision. But I have to say, if your program is taking an _hour_ to insert a million items to a list, that's really shockingly inefficient. I can't imagine it taking more than a few seconds.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Well, BST implementation does it in less than second. Point of this assignment is to compare implementations with lists and BST-s. BTW. I just wondered is result I get normal, I was not asking for fixing of code.

Comment: Still, @joks almost an hour for a million keys is way too long. You are asking about why a certain method takes longer than another method, but it seems that your methods are not implemented correctly. For instance, when inserting a new key in an unordered list, are you traversing the whole list everytime in order to insert at the end? (you could insert at the head faster, or keep a pointer to the tail to insert faster). For all we know, you could may be iterating through the list to find the index at which to insert, then calling your own insert method at index $i$ which again iterates to $i$

Comment: For the second method, how do you order the list? Is it constructed in such a way that it is ordered, or do you sort it somehow?

Comment: @JimN New key is inserted at the head in first example. In both examples insert methods are O(1) (all search is done in search method).

Comment: @user53923 When adding new key to (ordered) list first I find position of first larger key and return address of its predecessor to insert method which inserts element in right place. (so no sorting is done)

Comment: Is there any chance you are mis-labeling your ordered or unordered tests? :) the reported numbers are very strange. Those numbers are just on find() calls? and does not include inserts?

Comment: @JimN Hahaha. Nope, checked multiple times. Yes, those are numbers just for search function (just loop part of it, to be precise).

Comment: Maybe the following plays a role in the difference you see: in the unordered list example the elements in the list are likely stored in memory in the same order as in the list (thus, you traverse them in the same order as they are stored in memory - which is generally good because of caching,etc). In the second example, the order in the list does not match the order in which the elements are created (worse for caching).This is just a guess, all depends on your implentation, but it may be worth testing.

Comment: @user53923 mentions a good point with caching. Try swapping which of the tests you perform first. Is there a chance the random $k$ is generated and stored in one test and then the stored random keys are used in the second? I think we can keep guessing at things unless we see enough code to reproduce the time tests ourselves